# Creating new view from two other views with inner join, I just look at other same questions but I couldn't solve my problem

Tags: sql, sql-server

My first view named CTview:

[image]

and this is my second view named ITview:

[image]

so I want to inner join this two views and name it to Fundview and create a new column (with "value" named) for fundview which compute this formula : ([ITview].[IT] - [CTview].[CT])

at the end I wrote this query but this may not true:

```
CREATE VIEW Fundview AS 
SELECT a.C_DATE AS [date],a.CT,b.IT FROM CTview AS a
INNER JOIN ITview AS b ON a.C_Date = b.I_Date;
```

ITview and CTview doesn't known as object in my sql server so I can not use them.
(sorry my English is not so really good!)

Comment: Why haven't you included the formula you want to calculate?

Comment: @GordonLinoff because I don't know how to do this,but I know how to do this with SSMS.

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to add the new column to the query:

```
CREATE VIEW Fundview AS 
SELECT a.C_DATE AS [date],a.CT,b.IT, b.IT-a.CT as value FROM CTview AS a
INNER JOIN ITview AS b ON a.C_Date = b.I_Date;
```

Comment: I believe you have a typo in your formula. `b.IT-a.IT` should be `b.IT-a.CT`. (Sorry. I'm ruthless about editing questions, but really hesitant about editing answers.)

Comment: But CTview and ITview doesn't known as System object in my sql server so I can not use them.